# The expected value of mean sum of square for the simple linear regression

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I need some help with this:
Consider the simple linear regression $y = β_0 + β_1*x + e$, $E(e)=0$, $Var(e)=σ^2$ and $e$ uncorrelated.
I need to show that $E(MS_R)=σ^2+β_1^2*S_{xx}$, how do I do this?
Here $MS_R$ is the mean sum of squares for the regression, $MS_R=∑_{i=1}^n(ŷ_i-y ̅)^2$ and $S_{xx}=∑_{i=1}^n(x_i-x ̅)^2$
And also; $E(MS_{Res})=σ^2$.
Please help me MathStack, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simple regression model $MS_{reg} = SS_{reg}$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[MS_R|X] &= \mathbb{E} [\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{Y}_i - \bar{Y}_n)^2 | X]\\
                   &=\mathbb{E}[\sum(\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1X_i - \bar{Y}_n)|X]\\
                   &=\mathbb{E}[\sum( \hat{\beta}_1\bar{X}_i- \bar{X}_n)^2|X]\\
                   & = \sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2\mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}_1^2|X]\\
                   &=\sum(x_i-\bar{x}_n)^2\frac{\sigma_{\epsilon}^2}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x}_n)^2} + \beta_1^2\sum(x_i - \bar{x}_n)^2\\
                   & = \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 + \beta_1^2\sum(x_i - \bar{x}_n)^2.
\end{align}
For $\mathbb{E}[MSres|X]$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[MS_{res}|X] & = \frac{1}{n-2}\mathbb{E}[SST - SS_{reg}|X]\\
                       & = \frac{1}{n-2}\mathbb{E}[\sum (Y_i - \bar{Y}_n)^2|X]-\frac{1}{n-2}\mathbb{E}[SS_{reg}|X],
\end{align}
now plug in the previous result in the second summand and for the first one -
 substitute $Y_i$ and $\bar{Y}_n$ with $\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon_i$ and $\beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{X}_n + \bar{\epsilon}_n$ and then just proceed with the algebra until you get the required result. 
Namely,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[MS_{res}|X] & = \frac{1}{n-2}\mathbb{E}[\sum (\beta_1(X_i - \bar{X}_n) + (\epsilon_i - \bar{\epsilon}))^2|X]-\frac{1}{n-2}\mathbb{E}[SS_{reg}|X]\\
                       & = \frac{\beta_1^2}{n-2}\sum  (x_i - \bar{x}_n)^2 + \frac{1}{n-2}\mathbb{E}[(\epsilon_i - \bar{\epsilon}))^2|X]-\frac{1}{n-2}\mathbb{E}[SS_{reg}|X]\\
                       & = \frac{(n-1)\sigma^2 - \sigma^2 }{n-2}\\ 
                       & = \sigma^2.
\end{align}

Comment: For the second part isn't $E(MS_{Res}=E( ∑((y_i -ŷ_i)^2)/(n-2))$ and $E∑(y_i -ŷ_i)^2)$ $=$ $E$ $∑(β_0+β_1 * x_i + e_i - β^_0 - β ̂_1 * x̅)^2)$ =E∑(e_i^2). Does that mean that $E∑(e_i^2)/(n-2)=σ^2$?

Comment: I f*cked up above, cannot manage to do the estimated Beta sign. Below is as good as it gets.   
For the second part isn't $E(MS_{Res})=E( ∑((y_i -ŷ_i)^2)/(n-2))$ and $E(∑(y_i -ŷ_i)^2)$ $=$ $E∑(β_0+β_1 * x_i + e_i - β ̂_0 - β ̂_1 * x̅)^2)$ $=$ $E(∑(e_i^2)$. Does that mean that $E∑(e_i^2)/(n-2)=σ^2$?

Comment: You are right. I've skipped some steps. Pls see the edited answer. And \hat{\beta} - for the hat sign

Comment: Ok, one last question and I'll be forever grateful. How does $E(ϵ_i - ϵ¯)^2 = n*σ^2-σ^2$?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}\sum (\epsilon_i - \bar{\epsilon}_n)^2  = ( \mathbb{E}\sum_i \epsilon_i^2 - n\mathbb{E}\bar{\epsilon}^2) = n\sigma^2 - \sigma^2$